# iTerm2 zsh oh-my-zsh open tab with same directory

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

Hi i just installed iTerm2 and tried to open a tab with the same directory as the tab that open it.

I tried [Open a new tab in the same directory](https://superuser.com/questions/232835/zsh-open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory) answer but still can't get the directory working.

It worked fine in terminal.app but when im using iTerm it's not work anymore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It [does work for me](http://screencast.com/t/bxdgKDfFqr). Are you sure your `.zshrc` has the `osx` plugin loaded? Check for the existence of the function with:

```
$ type tab
tab is a shell function
```

Then, in your terminal, simply run the command

```
tab
```

This will [execute the appropriate line in the `tab()` function](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/osx/osx.plugin.zsh#L30) defined by the `osx` plugin. If it works for Terminal.app, it should also work for iTerm2.

---

In order to map this command to a custom keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, do the following. Open up Automator.app and create a new *Service*. Set it to receive *No Input* from *iTerm.app* and drag *Run AppleScript* from the left to the editing pane.

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current terminal
        tell current session
            write text "tab"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

That should look like this:

[image]

Save it under *Open new Tab with zsh* or similar. Now, under *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, under *Services*, assign a keyboard shortcut.

Note that not all keyboard shortcuts are available, and you can't just override <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> since this is a built-in one.

[image]

Comment: Note: You **need** to actually type `tab` into the terminal to create a new tab. Not through *Shell » New Tab* or ⌘T

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a custom command anymore...

Preferences > Profiles > [Profile Name] > General > Working Directory > "Reuse previous tab's directory"

Source: https://code.google.com/p/iterm2/issues/detail?id=420#c14

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding -l to Command in my Profile settings. [image: fix iterm]