# Prevent zsh from setting the current prompt to the name of the variable that points to this path

Tags: macos, command-line, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

This is related to [Open a new tab in the same directory](https://superuser.com/questions/232835/zsh-open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory).
I have installed oh-my-zsh recently and it certainly kicks.
I have some custom variables, like $WORKSPACE which I use to get around easily.
And when I am inside one of those paths the prompt gets set to the name of the variable, for example `~WORKSPACE/project $` .
This breaks the "Open tab in the same directory feature" which I love so much.
And whats puzzling me most here is that this does not happen for the ZSH variable.
So cd $ZSH gives a prompt like `~/.oh-my-zsh $`. And as far as I know they are bot set the same way in my .zshrc

```
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
WORKSPACE=$HOME/workspace
```

Comment: Figured out as I was writing.

The problem was that I was setting the custom vars after oh-my-zsh was loaded.
Moving them up solved the problem, but I still dont understand what happened. Maybe its a oh-my-zsh feature?

Comment: If you've answered your question, you should type it up as an "answer" below and accept it.  It will be more useful to people that land here in the future. :)

Comment: Oops, forgot to. SU had a time period before I could do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh-my-zsh was setting `auto_name_dirs` which caused this behaviour.
I just commented out that line from lib/directories.zsh and everything went back to the way I wanted them.

Comment: So... is this the answer to the question?  I still don't know how to prevent zsh from setting the current prompt to the name of the variable that points to this path...

Comment: Updated the answer, thanks for bringing this up again.

Comment: Dont forget to vote me up! :)