# How to prevent zsh from showing environment variable name instead of current path?

Tags: zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

I'm using "oh-my-zsh".

I have an environment variable set to the current path, let's say:

```
PROJECT=/home/me/projects/client/project
```

and my zsh prompt looks like this:

```
me@my-machine:~PROJECT$
```

while my bash prompt looks like this:

```
me@my-machine:~/projects/client/project$
```

How can I configure the zsh prompt to behave like bash?
I mean, I would like to see the full path in the prompt, even when there's a variable pointing to it.

Answer (score 3):

Set your zsh prompt to use `%d` instead of `%~`

I'm not sure how oh-my-zsh implements it, but I'd start looking in ~/.zshrc

More info can be found at `man zshmisc` (search for 'EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES')

Answer (score 0):

Finally answered here:

[Prevent zsh from setting the current prompt to the name of the variable that points to this path](https://superuser.com/questions/470995/prevent-zsh-from-setting-the-current-prompt-to-the-name-of-the-variable-that-poi/479920?noredirect=1#comment719146_479920)

The question was a duplicate but the other one didn't had an answer until now.