# new tab doesn't work as intended in zsh

Tags: zsh, terminal.app

I want to open a new tab in same directory but it always move home directory. e.g.(~/sample press cmd + t, then ~)
These are results of commands which seems to relevant

```
cat /etc/shells
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/bash


 which zsh
/bin/zsh
```

macOS mojave 10.14.6

zsh version zsh 5.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser!
https://superuser.com/questions/232835/open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory - have you configured it properly? If yes, then please clarify what doesn't work and how you've configured it. If not, then this should be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In the macOS Terminal app, you can set this in the preferences.

1. In the Terminal app, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (command + comma) to open preferences.
2. There, in General, under "New tabs open with", select "Same Working Directory":
   [image]